# Bigcommerce webhooks not working

Tags: php, api, webhooks, bigcommerce

I have generated access_token and subscribed to webhooks successfully as guided here http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/webhooks/quickstart.

Verified that webhooks are active and destination url is also correct with following request-

```
curl -XGET -H 'X-Auth-Client: [client_id]' -H 'X-Auth-Token: [auth_token]' https://hooks-beta.bigcommerce.com/producer/store/[store_key]
```

However I am not receiving triggers for subscribed events. Is there anything else that I have to do to listen to webhook events?

Comment: Can you check logging on your application to see that the destination url is being hit when you expect? You may need to configure your application to allow cross site posting for the destination URL you've given.

Comment: Hi Pratik, did you ever get this working?  I'm experiencing the same issue. I successfully subscribed to the /store/product/updated event, but I'm not receiving any requests from BigCommerce when products updated.  I've checked my apache logs, and nothing appears.  I also tested my webhook destination by manually issuing a POST request, and it works correctly. Did you have any luck figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the exact same thing, and then I realized that my intermediate SSL certificates were not loaded correctly. Once I established those through my CA and host, the triggers were finally hitting my server.