# Bigcommerce webhooks history

Tags: bigcommerce, webhooks

I'm following the instructions here https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/webhooks to set up webhooks to initiate some third-party order processing.  All webhooks all instaled, but I don't see any data?

Where can I get history information about Webhooks?

Comment: I'm having lots of trouble with webhooks as well. Are you required to create an app in-order to create a webhook? This is all so easy in Shopify...

Comment: Lots of similar questions on SO, no one has the answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441912/bigcommerce-webhook-not-firing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207630/bigcommerce-webhooks-not-working
Where are you, @bigcommerce?